# Unexpected behaviour of javascript timestamp

Tags: javascript, cordova

I use phoneGap Geo-location API to get current position in which i got time-stamp also.

```
alert(data[0].timestamp);
alert(new Date(data[0].timestamp).getTime());
```

where `data[0].timestamp = "2013-12-03T19:09:58.859Z"`

in web browser the second alert shows `1386097798859` whereas when i built and test app in mobile then it alert as `NaN`
I don't understand why it happens?

Comment: What browser and what mobile platform?

Comment: it works fine in firefox, chrome but when i finally built for mobile `Android App` then it show NaN

Comment: It's a ISODate format. Try to use `Date.parse` or use javascript [library](http://momentjs.com/) which can parse a lot of date formats.

Comment: OK i try then post the result

Answer (score 1):

It's a ISODate format. Try to use `Date.parse` or use momentjs javascript [library](http://momentjs.com/) which can parse a lot of date formats.

Also there is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/kitcambridge/1139058) with `Date.parse` polifyll.